# I have a question about postgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I am new to programming. I used PostgreSQL because I needed a database program.

I made a data file using initdb.exe

```sh
initdb.exe -U postgres -A password -E utf8 -W -D D:\Develop\postgresql-10.17-2-windows-x64-binaries\data
```

This method is called a data cluster.
I have put a lot of information into this data file.
Now I want to transfer the data to another computer and use it.
How do I import and use files created using a cluster?
I want to register and use it in pgAdmin4.
What should I do?

I am using a Windows 10 operating system. A solution similar to loading a cluster is required.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for detailed step-by-step description, blueprint or how to for setting up and configure a database with replication or cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you want to transfer to another 64-bit Windows system, you can just shut down the server and copy the data directory. Register a service with `pg_ctl register` if you want.

To copy the data to a different operating system, you have to use `pg_dumpall` and restore with `psql`. pgAdmin won't help you there (it is not an administration tool, as its name would suggest).